# Formatting a drupal email with html - location of files?

Tags: php, html, drupal, formatting, html-email

I have been asked to create a html formatted email but the whole site uses drupal. I have never used it before and I am struggling to find the piece of code that i need to edit. 
Would anyone be able to shed some light on the file name or directory that i should be looking in?? As soon as I know that I have the template ready to copy over.

I believe that the drupal installation is Drupal 6.3.

As far as i can tell it is using default drupal, the hosting is not cloud and i haven't found any template files but thats not to say they arent there. There are themes installed but i did not see one that formats the email content as i have been asked to do. I have found contact files but i'm unsure which ones would change the email layout.

Comment: You should improve your question including Drupal version.

Comment: Hi i literally have no idea what version it is. I've been thrown in at the deep end part way through a project.

Comment: it uses Drupal 6.3 i believe.

Comment: Every time you add some information, please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: thanks. I'm a newbie. I apologise. lol. :P

Comment: No problem. :) It was just an advice.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on a few other factors;

1. What module are they using to send out email (Default Drupal, or
   something like simplenews?)
2. What hosting are they using? (If it's
   cloud hosting, you may need to specify validated send addresses
   etc.)
3. There may be templates in various locations.  What templates are installed?  Are they only used for this site, or is it a multisite install?
4. It might be in a template file, or it could be done programatically.

Comment: as far as i can tell it is using default drupal, the hosting is not cloud and i haven't found any template files but thats not to say they arent there. There are themes installed but i did not see one that formats the email content as i have been asked to do. I have however found the contact files but i'm unsure which ones would change the email layout.